# What are plants that are good to grow in pots?

Tags: trees, containers

I live in India and want to have the balcony of my apartment look more colorful, fresh and blossoming. Can anyone suggest which plants are suitable to grow in pots, and how to care for them to encourage healthy growth?

Kindly suggest plants that emits oxygen as I live in the middle of a city and pollution is high.

Comment: All plants emit oxygen.  None emit significant quantities (individually).  You really need something which has plenty of foliage to filter particulates.

Comment: @Roshni I am struggling to think of a plant that couldn't, at least for a time, be grown in a pot.

Comment: This is far too broad IMO. The climate in India has huge differences in temperature and humidity in different regions. We don't even know which direction your balcony is facing, and therefore how much direct sun it gets during the day.

Comment: @Rob exactly - you can even grow a California Redwood as a bonsai, if you really want to.

Comment: @Roshni  Can you add more details about your location and a picture of your balcony including which direction it faces?  Otherwise this question might be closed as it's hard to answer on the what you have told us